# Uncompress a .gz file and ready it chunk by chunk

Tags: ruby, compression

I have a number of quite big .gz files that I want to read. But I don't want to read each file all at once because it may hurt RAM, instead I want to read it chunk by chunk. How can I do that? In the documentation it describes a traditional approach by reading a whole file:

```
Zlib::GzipReader.open('hoge.gz')  do |gz|
  print gz.read
end

File.open('hoge.gz') do |f|
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(f)
  print gz.read
  gz.close
end
```

Comment: `GzipReader#readline` or `GzipReader#readpartial` can do just that http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipReader.html.

Comment: That's the answer.  Why not put it in an answer?

Answer (score 4):

No examples of this anywhere. I needed to read the documentation.

```
require 'zlib'

def read_gz_by_chunk

infile = open("file_name.gz")
rgz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(infile)

   while(!rgz.eof)
     data = rgz.readpartial(256)
     # do stuff
     puts data
   end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. Basically this method was used to fetch *json.gz* from the URL and then read it by chunks to a string which is then parsed as **JSON**. You don't necessarily to download the json.gz you can just reference your file. I think someone can use this to build their own method from it.

```
require 'zlib'

def parse_large_json_gz_file()
  gz_file = # reference your file here

  json_string = ''

  file = Zlib::GzipReader.open(gz_file)
  until file.eof?
    json_string += file.readpartial(1024 * 1024)
  end

  JSON.parse(json_string)
end
```